# Access repetitive controls in FXML from the controller without having to give an ID to each control

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

This is what my **FXML** hierarchy looks like:

- **AnchorPane**

  - **VBox**

    - **HBox**

      - ComboBox:String : [Channel Name]
      - TextField : [Delay before start]
      - Button : [Triggers recording start]
    - **HBox**

      - ComboBox:String : [Channel Name]
      - TextField : [Delay before start]
      - Button : [Triggers recording start]
    - **HBox**

      - ComboBox:String : [Channel Name]
      - TextField : [Delay before start]
      - Button : [Triggers recording start]

I want a way to get to the controls inside of each hbox `-in my controller-` , without having to give an id to each control inside of it.

> What i'm currenty doing is using the index of each element to get a
>   hold of it like this:

```
@FXML
public void startRecording(MouseEvent event) {
    ObservableList<Node> curChildNodes = ((Node) event.getTarget()).getParent().getChildrenUnmodifiable();
    String               channelName   = ((ComboBox<String>) (curChildNodes.get(0))).getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    long                 delay         = Long.parseLong(((TextField) curChildNodes.get(1)).getText());

    Stream stream = new Stream(channelName, delay);
    Recorder recorder = new Recorder(stream);
    recorder.startAfterDelay();
}
```

The method i'm using can get **tedious** if i have more controls in that HBox, or if i decide change their position in the hierarchy.

**Is there a better way to do it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate FXML file (with its own controller class) representing the `HBox` with the `ComboBox`, `TextField`, and `Button`. Then use [`<fx:include>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements) to include it in your main FXML file.

You can reference the controller instances created for each instance of the included FXML files in the "main" controller using the ["Nested Controllers"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) technique if needed.

So you can create something like this (I'll call this `ChannelControls.fxml`):

```xml
<HBox xmlns:fx="..." fx:controller="myapp.ChannelController">
    <ComboBox fx:id="channel"/>
    <TextField fx:id="delay"/>
    <Button text="Start" fx:id="start" onAction="startRecording"/>
</HBox>
```

with a controller

```
public class ChannelController {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> channel ;
    @FXML
    private TextField delay ;
    @FXML
    private Button start ;

    @FXML
    private void startRecording(ActionEvent event) {
        String channelName = channel.getValue();
        long delayTime = Long.parseLong(delay.getText());
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then in your "main" fxml, you can do

```xml
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="..." fx:controller="myapp.MainController" >
    <VBox>
        <fx:include src="ChannelControls.fxml"/>
        <fx:include src="ChannelControls.fxml"/>
        <fx:include src="ChannelControls.fxml"/>
    </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

If you need to access the instances of `ChannelController` in the main controller, add `fx:id`s to the `<fx:include>`s:

```xml
<fx:include src="ChannelControls.fxml" fx:id="channel1" />
<fx:include src="ChannelControls.fxml" fx:id="channel2" />
<!-- etc -->
```

and then you can access the controllers by appending `"Controller"` to the `fx:id` value:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private ChannelController channel1Controller ;
    @FXML
    private ChannelController channel2Controller ;

    public void initialize() {
        // do anything you need with channel1Controller, etc.
    }
}
```

---

A slight variant on this is to implement the `HBox` with its pieces as a ["Custom Component"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components). This really just reverses the creational roles of the FXML file and the controller class (so instead of you loading the FXML file, which creates the controller automatically, you create the controller, which loads the FXML automatically). So you can create

```
public class ChannelControls extends HBox {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> channel ;
    @FXML
    private TextField delay ;
    @FXML
    private Button start ;

    public ChannelControls() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader("ChannelControls.fxml");
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            // this is pretty much fatal:
            throw new UncheckedIOException(exc);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void startRecording(ActionEvent event) {
        String channelName = channel.getValue();
        long delayTime = Long.parseLong(delay.getText());
        // ...
    }

    // other methods as needed
}
```

The only change to `ChannelControls.fxml` is to the root element: note that you must remove the `fx:controller` attribute:

```xml
<fx:root type="HBox" xmlns:fx="...">
    <ComboBox fx:id="channel"/>
    <TextField fx:id="delay"/>
    <Button text="Start" fx:id="start" onAction="startRecording"/>
</fx:root>
```

Now your main fxml file just needs

```xml
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="..." fx:controller="myapp.MainController" >
    <VBox>
        <ChannelControls/>
        <ChannelControls/>
        <ChannelControls/>
    </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

You can add `fx:id`s to the `<ChannelControls>` elements, and inject them directly into the main controller if you need. This approach makes it slightly easier to expose properties and methods in the `ChannelControls` class and access them in the main controller, imho.

Comment: Not a single javafx question passes without an answer from the one and only **James_D**! I will try that now, thank you!

Comment: Thank you a ton James! Worked flawlessly!

Comment: P.S I appreciate you taking to time to write this comprehensive answer, not many do that.